# Understanding Bison with no declared type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, bison, lex

I have the following code below and I am receiving the following error

parser.y:111.47-48: error: $$ for the midrule at $5 of ‘statement’ has no declared type
111 |         REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} ';'|

I know it's generated because I didn't declare a type for something in the statement, I need help understanding line 111.  Also the REAL_LITERAL is a float, that I should add a float to the union and create token like this %token <f_value>REAL_LITERAL.

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

#include "math.h"
#include "values.h"
#include "listing.h"
#include "symbols.h"

int yylex();
void yyerror(const char* message);

Symbols<int> symbols;

int result;
double *params;
%}

%define parse.error verbose

%union
{
    CharPtr iden;
    Operators oper;
    int value;
}

%token <iden> IDENTIFIER
%token <value>INT_LITERAL REAL_LITERAL BOOL_LITERAL CASE TRUE FALSE

%token ARROW

%token <oper> ADDOP MULOP RELOP OROP NOTOP REMOP EXPOP
%token ANDOP

%token BEGIN_ BOOLEAN END ENDREDUCE FUNCTION INTEGER IS REDUCE RETURNS
%token THEN WHEN
%token ELSE ENDCASE ENDIF IF OTHERS REAL

%type <value> body statement_ statement reductions expression binary relation term
    factor primary
%type <oper> operator

%left OROP
%left ANDOP
%left RELOP
%left ADDOP
%left MULOP REMOP
%right EXPOP
%left NOTOP
%%

function:   
    function_header optional_variable body {result = $3;} ;
    
function_header:    
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER parameters RETURNS type ';' |
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER RETURNS type ';' |
    FUNCTION IDENTIFIER optional_parameters RETURNS type ';' |
    error ';' ;
    
optional_variable:
    optional_variable variable |
    error ';' ;
    ;

variable:   
    IDENTIFIER ':' type IS statement_ {symbols.insert($1, $5);} ;

variables:
    variable variables |
    ;

type:
    INTEGER |
    BOOLEAN ;

optional_parameters:
    parameters |
    ;
    
parameters:
    parameter ',' parameters |
    parameter ;
    
parameter:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type ;

type:
    INTEGER |
    REAL |
    BOOLEAN ;

body:
    BEGIN_ statement_ END ';' {$$ = $2;} ;

statement_:
    statement ';' |
    error ';' {$$ = 0;} ;
    
statement:
    expression |
    REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} ';'|
    IF expression THEN statement_ ELSE statement_ ENDIF
    {
        if ($2 == true) {
                $$ = $4;
            }
            else {
                $$ = $6;
            }
    }';' /*|
    CASE expression IS cases OTHERS ARROW statement_ ENDCASE
    {$$ = $<value>4 == $1 ? $4 : $7;} ;

cases:
    cases case
    {$$ = $<value>1 == $1 ? $1 : $2;} |
    %empty {$$ = NAN;};

case:
    case WHEN INT_LITERAL ARROW statement_ |
    ;
*/
operator:
    ADDOP |
    RELOP |
    EXPOP |
    MULOP ;

reductions:
    reductions statement_ {$$ = evaluateReduction($<oper>0, $1, $2);} |
    {$$ = $<oper>0 == ADD ? 0 : 1;} ;

expression:
    expression OROP binary {$$ = $1 || $3;} |
    binary;
    
binary:
    binary ANDOP relation {$$ = $1 && $3;} |
    relation ;

relation:
    relation RELOP term {$$ = evaluateRelational($1, $2, $3);} |
    term ;

term:
    term ADDOP factor {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} |
    factor ;
      
factor:
    factor MULOP primary {$$ = evaluateArithmetic($1, $2, $3);} |
    primary ;

primary:
    '(' expression ')' {$$ = $2;} |
    INT_LITERAL |
    IDENTIFIER {if (!symbols.find($1, $$)) appendError(UNDECLARED, $1);} ;

%%

void yyerror(const char* message)
{
    appendError(SYNTAX, message);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    firstLine();
    yyparse();
    if (lastLine() == 0)
        cout << "Result = " << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in your reduce .. endreduce do you actually mean to have the ';' follow the action block?

Comment: yes, that is the code that was provided and I was to extend it.  It shouldn't be there?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir That was my problem, I should not have ; follow the action block

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that in-rule actions do not get a default type in bison (unlike yacc).  So in your action

```
REDUCE operator reductions ENDREDUCE {$$ = $3;} ';'
```

there's no `%type` for `$$` so you need to specify it explicitly -- perhaps something like `{ $<value>$ = $3; }`.  That's equivalent to what yacc would do here, as it gives in-rule actions the same type as the lhs, even though there's not really anything connecting them.

The bigger issue is that this really makes no sense -- an in-rule action like this does NOT set the value for the symbol being reduced.  That can only happen in the end-of-rule action.  So this is just copying a value to a temp and then throwing it away, never doing anything with it.  The implicit end-rule action just does `{ $$ = $1; }` which makes no sense as `statement` and `REDUCE` have different types.